# Cannot Merge Node error: Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have 2 CSV files which I want to convert into a Neo4j database. They look like this:

```
first file:

name,enzyme
Aminomonas paucivorans,M1.Apa12260I
Aminomonas paucivorans,M2.Apa12260I
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,M1.BceNI
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,M2.BceNI

second file 

name,motif
Aminomonas paucivorans,GGAGNNNNNGGC
Aminomonas paucivorans,GGAGNNNNNGGC
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,CCCNNNNNCTC
```

As you can see the common factor is the Name of the organism and the. Each Organism will have a few Enzymes and each Enzyme will have 1  Motif. Motifs can be same between enzymes . I used the following statement to create my database:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/Desktop.n_e.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(e:Enzyme { name: csvLine.enzyme})
CREATE (o)-[:has_enzyme]->(e)

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/Desktop/n_m.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(m:Motif { name: csvLine.motif})
CREATE (o)-[:has_motif]->(m)
```

However I keep getting the error `Cannot merge node using null property value for name (Failure when processing URL 'file:C:/Users/Desktop/n_e.csv' on line 2. No rows seem to have been committed. Note that this information might not be accurate.)`. I googled the issue but got no working solution to this. I made sure my `CSV` is "vanilla" csv (no spaces, only comma separated). but I keep getting this problem. i am using the `2.1.3` version of Neo4j. Any help will be greately appreciated.

File 1: [n_e.csv](http://pastebin.com/JUj9ws5y)
File 2: [n_m.csv](http://pastebin.com/Lmh5V6Un)

Comment: Hello letsc, I also get this kind of error. What solved it for me was that I inserted also `FIELDTERMINATOR ','`. Hope it helps with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Update to 2.1.5
2. read this blog post on how to check that [your data is read](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/) correctly.
3. Also you might check that you don't have windows newlines or an UTF 2-byte file preamble
4. check that you have an index for :Organism(name) and :Enzyme(name) and :Motif(name) in place

In general try this and check the outputs:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/Desktop.n_e.csv" AS csvLine
RETURN csvLine
LIMIT 5

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/Desktop.n_e.csv" AS csvLine
RETURN csvLine.name,csvLine.enzyme 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I did try that. It executes with any error but the result shows as `Displaying 0 nodes , 0 relationships`. I have included a link to my `.csv` files in the question. . You can have a look at them. AFAIK they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was the spaces in header line. For example, a `CVS` file:

```
Name, Surname, City
Jan, Kowalski, Gdansk
```

so, the `Name` was imported fine, but the `Surname` was not recognized (was null),
as was space between comma and `Surname`, etc. After removing it, it started working.