# Can't MERGE with null values; 'Cannot merge node using null property value' in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a column in a csv that looks like this:

[image]

I am using this code to test how the splitting of the dates is working:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH
SPLIT(line.date_of_birth, '/') AS date_of_birth
return date_of_birth;
```

This code block works fine and gives me what I'd expect, which is a collection of three values for each date, or perhaps a `null` if there was no date ( e.g,

```
[4, 5, 1971]  
[0, 0, 2003]  
[0, 0, 2005]  
 . . .  
null  
null  
 . . .
```

My question is, what is this problem with the nulls that are created, and why can't I do a MERGE when there are nulls?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH
SPLIT(line.date_of_birth, '/') AS date_of_birth, line
MERGE (p:Person {
 date_of_birth: date_of_birth
});
```

This block above gives me the error:

```
Cannot merge node using null property value for date_of_birth
```

I have searched around and have only found [one other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267542/cannot-merge-node-error-neo4j) about this error, which has no answer. Other searches didn't help.

I was under the impression that if there isn't a value, then Neo4j simply doesn't create the element.

I figured maybe the node can't be generated since, after all, how can a node be generated if there is no value to generate it from? So, since I know there are no ID's missing, maybe I could MERGE with ID and date, so Neo4j always sees a value.

But this code didn't fare any better (same error message):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH
SPLIT(line.date_of_birth, '/') AS date_of_birth, line
MERGE (p:Person {
 ID: line.ID
,date_of_birth: date_of_birth
});
```

My next idea is that maybe this error is because I'm trying to split a null value on slashes?  Maybe the whole issue is due to the `SPLIT`.

But alas, same error when simplified to this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (p:Person {
 subject_person_id: line.subject_person_id
,date_of_birth: line.date_of_birth
});
```

So I don't really understand the cause of the error.  Thanks for looking at this.

**EDIT**

Both @stdob-- and @cybersam have both answered with equally excellent responses, if you came here via Google please consider them as if both were accepted

Comment: I get this error even though I have no null or empty values whatsoever.

Comment: Figured it out: you will also get this error when importing from CSV and the column is inside backticks (for ex. due to spaces) AND YOU HAVE FOREIGN CHARACTERS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @cybersam said,`MERGE` doesn't work well with queries where the properties are set within the scope in null. So, you can use [ON CREATE and ON MATCH](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html#_use_on_create_and_on_match):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
  'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
MERGE (p:Person {
  subject_person_id: line.subject_person_id
})
  ON CREATE SET p.date_of_birth = line.date_of_birth
  ON MATCH SET p.date_of_birth = line.date_of_birth
```

Comment: If`ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` do exactly the same `SET`, then just replace the 2 clauses with a single `SET`.

Answer (score 13):

Some Cypher queries, like [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/), do not work well with `NULL` values.

The somewhat tricky workaround for handling this situation with `MERGE` is to use the `FOREACH` clause to conditionally perform the `MERGE`. This query might work for you:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
FOREACH (x IN CASE WHEN line.date_of_birth IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
  MERGE (:Person {date_of_birth: SPLIT(line.date_of_birth, '/')})
);
```

[UPDATE with answer for "simplified" query]

Keep potentially-`null` properties out of your `MERGE` clause. Also, [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clauses must be carefully crafted to avoid creating unwanted extra nodes by limiting the properties specified in the `MERGE`.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///..some_csv.csv' AS line
MERGE (p:Person {subject_person_id: line.subject_person_id})
SET p.date_of_birth = line.date_of_birth
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that I've been rather fond of is to just tell cypher to skip rows in which the field of interest is NULL as follows:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT #
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///.../csv.csv' AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.somedatefield, delimiter) AS date
WHERE NOT line.somedatefield IS NULL

[THE REST OF YOUR QUERY INVOLVING THE FIELD]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution IMO.

Comment: `WHERE NOT` was key for me

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use `COALESCE(n.property?, {defaultValue})`

Comment: why the question mark after `property`? and are the {}s supposed to mean a required value as in the Backus-Naur notation?

Answer (score 0):

Following with Vojtech Ruzicka's approach, you can use something like this `your_value:COALESCE(line.your_value, 'default value')`

Link to the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce), in case you need more information.