# Neo4j display only one node for 1 to many relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i'm trying to solve a problem of the 1: many relationship display in neo4j. My dataset is as below

```
child,desc,type,parent
1,PGD,Exchange,0
2,MSE 1,MSE,1
3,MSE 2,MSE,1
4,MSE 3,MSE,1
5,MSE 4,MSE,1
6,BRAS 1,BRAS,2
6,BRAS 1,BRAS,3
7,BRAS 2,BRAS,4
7,BRAS 2,BRAS,5
10,NPE 1,NPE,6
11,NPE 2,NPE,7
12,OLT,OLT,10
12,OLT,OLT,11
13,FDC,FDC,12
14,FDP,FDP,13
15,Cust 1,Customer,14
16,Cust 2,Customer,14
17,Cust 3,Customer,14
```

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FTTH_sample.csv' AS line 
CREATE(:ftthsample
{child_id:line.child,
desc:line.desc,
type:line.type,
parent_id:line.parent});

//Relations 
match (child:ftthsample),(parent:ftthsample)
where child.child_id=parent.parent_id 
create (child)-[:test]->(parent)

//Query:
MATCH (child)-[childrel:test*]-(elem)-[parentrel:test*]->(parent) 
WHERE elem.desc='FDP'
RETURN child,childrel,elem,parentrel
```

It returns a display as below.

[image: output]

I want the duplicate nodes to be displayed as one. Newbie with Neo4J. Can anyone of the experts help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an error in your graph creation query. You have a few lines in your query specifying the same node multiple times, but with multiple parents:

```
6,BRAS 1,BRAS,2
6,BRAS 1,BRAS,3
```

I'm guessing you actually want this to be a single node, with parent relationships to nodes with the given parent ids, instead of two separate nodes.

Let's adjust your import query. Instead of using a CREATE on each line, we'll use MERGE, and just on the `child_id`, which seems to be your primary key (maybe consider just using `id` instead, as a node can have an id on its own, without having to consider the context of whether it's a parent or child). We can use the ON CREATE clause after MERGE to add in the remaining properties only if the MERGE resulted in node creation (instead of matching to an existing node.

That will ensure we only have one node created per `child_id`.

Rather than having to rematch the child, we can use the child node we just created, match on the parent, and create the relationship.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FTTH_sample.csv' AS line 
MERGE(child:ftthsample {child_id:line.child})
ON CREATE SET
child.desc = line.desc,
child.type = line.type

WITH child, line.parent as parentId
MATCH (parent:ftthsample)
WHERE parent.child_id = parentId
MERGE (child)-[:test]->(parent)
```

Note that we haven't added `line.parent` as a property. It's not needed, since we only use that to create relationships, and after the relationships are there, we won't need those again.

Comment: Sorry to bug you. Differing from the sample, my actual dataset has my id or join columns are string values .. and some child values may or may not have parent, the same goes with parent. 

That's probably the reason why it's throwing me the error
"Cannot merge node using null property value for child_id"

I tried the solution you have provided here, but still throwing the error ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794877/how-to-include-properties-with-null-values-using-neo4j-merge

Can you please check. Sorry to bug you again.

Comment: You're going to need to have some unique value to merge on. If you data originally came from a relational db, you would normally have some primary key id that you would use for the merge. Without some unique primary key, you won't be able to merge these nodes, because there's no way to tell which are unique. You could merge with all the properties instead of just the child_id, though I'm not sure if that gets you around the error.